# Heroku not setting property $PORT when deploying executable jar

Tags: spring-boot, heroku

I have a Gradle-Kotlin project that is a Spring boot project, and it runs a server on port 8080 by default.

When I compile and generate a jar with command ./gradlew bootJar, I can set up the server justing by executing this jar. I wanted to run this server remotely, so I used Heroku (heroku deploy:jar) to upload the .jar. I could upload the jar and start the server with Heroku and it detected the buildback as heroku/jvm. With command `heroku logs --tail` I could verify that the server compiled and was up and running... but on port 8080. That is, I could't reach the server using heroku's public app url (ex https://radiant-crag-94685.herokuapp.com/my-end-point)

Reading some docs, I came to the PORT configuration. So I created a file called application.yml and put it in src/main/resources folder. This .yml file contained the following:

```
server:
    port: $PORT
```

I generated the .jar file and uploaded to Heroku once more. But this time, the app crashed on its main class, with the message:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Integer] for value '$PORT'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "$PORT"
```

The exception was thrown here:

```
@SpringBootApplication
open class AutomatedTestsApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<AutomatedTestsApplication>(*args)
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It looks like you just aren't converting the environment variable (which is a string) to an integer when you use it in your application. Please [edit] your question and show us how you use `PORT`.

Comment: @Chris, I edited the original message mentioning the main class, but the port config is default, just like the main class. According to Heroku's doc, it's only necessary to include the application.yml (or properties) file and the SpringBoot app will use the port defined by var $PORT, which is supposed to be set by Heroku.

Comment: Thanks, I misread this earlier. It actually looks like your application is getting a literal `$PORT` instead of whatever port Heroku is assigning. I'm not familiar with Spring Boot; can you point me at the documentation you're referring to? Heroku does set the `PORT` environment variable on `web` dynos, but I'm not sure what Spring Boot does with it.

Comment: @Chris, here's the doc: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/setting-the-http-port-for-java-applications#spring-boot

Comment: I managed to fix it: first of all, there's a specific setup up for Spring Boot for setting a custom port: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-port#programmatic. This way, I don't even need the applicatiom.yml file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable in your application.yml like you have doing this:

```
server:
   port: ${PORT}
```

Alternatively, as you mentioned in your comment, I think it would be better to override via startup command using something like:

```
java -jar service.jar --server.port=${PORT}
```